# Netbeans Code highlighting for built in PHP functions

Tags: php, function, netbeans, syntax, highlighting

I can't seem to change the code highlighting for php built-in functions such as strlen() or preg_match. Is this even possible in netbeans? Because no matter what I try, it appears in the same color as plain text in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I create (or open) a PHP project. When you create a PHP project, irlt asks for the PHP version to do highlighting, show documentation, etc.
Did you already created or opened the project and is the file you are trying to edit part of the project?
That seems the cause for the bad highlighting.

Comment: yes the php file was created as part of a new php project. I tried different themes and it still doesn't fix it.